# Arbitrary folder redirection via Group Policy

Tags: group-policy

Is there a means to redirect an arbitrary folder via Group Policy?

A slightly bowdlerised version of the specific path I'm interested in:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\<PRODUCT>\<SUBFOLDER>\bin\
```

For context - standard folder redirection is being used including Roaming `%APPDATA%`

I may have other workarounds for the specific issue but I've tried to generalise here.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a script pushed by GPO to create a [MKLINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx) for that folder if you need another folder inside the redirected %APPDATA% for some users.

It would look like that

```
mklink /j C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\<PRODUCT>\<SUBFOLDER>\bin\
E:\Users\SpecialFolder
```

Please note that you need to give special access to the Group Policy Client (gpsvc) in the local machine to be able to create symbolic's link via GPO.  *SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege* to be exact (as seen [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009154/create-symlink-with-gpo) too)

```
sc privs gpsvc SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege/SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege/SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege/SeSecurityPrivilege/SeChangeNotifyPrivilege/SeCreatePermanentPrivilege/SeShutdownPrivilege/SeLoadDriverPrivilege/SeRestorePrivilege/SeBackupPrivilege/SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff. I'll certainly try that out. Granting those additional rights will be easy to do since we're dealing with a Citrix XA farm of a few servers.

Comment: To close this off, mklink didn't work. Ultimately we were able to coerce the supplier to provide an alternative version of their client software that was able to use the %APPDATA% system variable.

Comment: @JonathanStockwell ah, good. thanks for the feedback